# Why varray is called as variable sized array in oracle when it is bounded in nature?

Tags: oracle, varray

I was learning collections in oracle and came across Varrays. It says that Varrays are of fixed sized with consecutive subscripts then why we say it as Variable sized array?

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I though VARRAY stood for Variable Array because it's an array of variables.  However, the documentation does actually say "Variable-size array" [(citation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#sthref1009).  I have no idea what the reason for this is :(

---

I wouldn't sweat over it.  In real life we almost always use nested table collections.  Flexibility is much more useful than a fixed-size constraint.  The one big advantage of VARRAYs is that their elements are guaranteed to keep their order, which is not true of nested tables.

---

A thought occurs.  When we talk about this datatype we usually pronounce it *vee array*.  If it was called Fixed-size Array that would be *eff array*, and so open to misinterpretation.  One for the native English speakers :D

Comment: I've wondered about this before. I'm guessing that within the fixed, upper bounds, the actual array length may still be variable. It's not a very compelling reason to call those arrays *"variable"* though...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what [the manual has to say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIJHD):

> *A varray (variable-size array) is an array whose number of elements can vary from zero (empty) to the declared maximum size. To access an element of a varray variable, use the syntax variable_name(index). The lower bound of index is 1; the upper bound is the current number of elements*

So the *maximum* number of elements is fixed, but the *current* number of elements is variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a_horse_with_no_name's explanation:

According to the VARRAY section found in [this Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#i468598):

> When you define a varray, you specify the maximum number of elements it can contain, although **you can change this number later**. The number of elements in an array is the size of the array. **Oracle allows arrays to be of variable size, which is why they are called varrays.**

So the naming convention seems to arise from two key points:

1) Even though you must set the maximum size of the VARRAY, there's nothing stopping you from setting it again, meaning its size can *vary over time*.

2) To restate the quote, Oracle allows VRRAYS to be of *variable size*. The *user* defines the value of said "size variable" on the array.